# lxml xpath get text between two nested tables

Tags: python, xpath, nested, lxml

I have a html that has nested tables. I wish to find the text between a outside table and inside tables. I thought this is a classic question but so far hasn't find the answer. What I have come up with is
`tree.xpath(//p[not(ancestor-or-self::table)])`. But this isn't working but because all text descends from the outside table. Also just use `preceding::table` isn't enough because the text can surrounds the inside table.

For an conceptual example if a table looks liek this `[...text1...[inside table No.1]...text2...[inside table No.2]...text3...]`, how can I get the `text1/2/3` only without being contaminated by texts from the `inside tables No.1&2`. Maybe this is my thought, is it possible to build a concept of table layer via xpath, so I can tell lxml or other libraries that "Give me all text between layer 0 and 1"

Below is a simplified sample html file. In reality, the outside table may contains many nested tables but I just want the text between the most outside table and its 1st nested tables. Thanks folks!

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <p> text I want </p>
        <div> they can be in different types of nodes </div>
        <table>
            <tr><td><p> unwanted text </p></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td><u> unwanted text</u></td></tr> 
                </table>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
        <p> text I also want </p>
        <div> as long as they're inside the root table and outside the first-level inside tables </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <u> they can be between the first-level inside tables </u>
        <table>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

And it returns `["text I want", "they can be in different types of nodes", "text I also want", "as long as they're inside the root table and outside the first-level inside tables", "they can be between the first-level inside tables"]`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the XPaths that could do this, if the outer most table is the root element:

```
/table/descendant::table[1]/preceding::p
```

Here, you traverse to the first descendant `table` of the outermost `table`, and then select all its preceding `p` elements.

If not, you will have to take a different approach of accessing the `p` elements in between the `tables`, may be using `generate-id()` function.

Comment: Yes, the outside table is the root. That's the only thing I am sure of. Would it work if texts are not in the <p>, in reality they could in in <u>, <span>, <td>...my files are some messed up

Comment: @Skywalker326, you should add the information to your question

Comment: @Skywalker326 if you want only the text nodes, you can use `preceding::text()` instead in the xpath and so on for more specific traversals e.g., `preceding::div/text()` etc.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS Yes, I am using this expression for now. But I am afraid I just tested it on 50+ html files while there are 100K file in total. I suspect there will be cases that the text surrounds the inside tables, in which case preceding won't work. For example if a table looks like this [...text1...[inside table No.1]...text2...[inside table No.2]...text3...], how can I get the text1/2/3 only without being contaminated by texts from inside table No.1&2. Is it possible to build a concept of table layer via xpath, so I can express that "Give me all text between layer 0 and 1".

Comment: @Skywalker326 Can you please add a sample input and tell us the required output out of the it.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS Just added it!